# Vina for loop not executing properly

Tags: python, docking

I have a code i have been woking on to get multiple ligand relating to a single receptor and then dock them basically trying virtual screening.

I was at the final step to basically do the virtual screening part but for some reason vina is just not working in for loop. I am working in colab and i tried to run the code outside the loop where it executes perfectely but in for loop it doesn't work.

here is the code:

```py
c_file = '/content/7y89/DOCKING/config_file'
receptor_file = '/content/7y89/7y89_receptor.pdbqt'


for ligand_file in os.listdir(dck_fold):
    if ligand_file.endswith(".pdbqt"):
        ligand_path = os.path.join(dck_fold, f"'{ligand_file}'")
        output_path = os.path.join(EXP_FLD, f"'docking_{ligand_file}'")
        tee = os.path.join(dck_fold, f"'{ligand_file}'_output.log")

        vina = f'%vina --config {c_file} --receptor {receptor_file} --ligand {ligand_path} --out {output_path} | tee {tee}'
        print(vina)

       try:
            os.chdir('/content/vina')
            subprocess.call(vina, shell=True)
            print(f'Successfully processed: {ligand_file}')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error processing: {ligand_file}')
            print(f'Error details: {str(e)}')
```

i used the double and single quotes so that the code does not break when a weird ligand name is there